# Why does'n update default checked nodes of a tree?

Tags: reactjs, tree, redux, antd

I have a component which uses a `Tree` component inside itself and it should be updated after fetching some keys from server and show checked keys inside tree. the component is like:

```js
const AccessTree = ({ urls, models, onCheck, checkedKeys }) => {
  console.log('checked keys:=>', checkedKeys);
  return (
    <Tree
      defaultCheckedKeys={checkedKeys}
      onCheck={node => onCheck(node)}
      defaultExpandedKeys={["something"]}
      checkable>
      <TreeNode
        title={'something'}
        key="auth">
        {models.map(model => {

          return (
              <TreeNode title={model} key={model}>
                {urls[model].map(item =>
                  {
                    return (
                      <TreeNode title={item.method} key={item.id}/>
                    )
                  }
                )}
              </TreeNode>
          )
        })}
      </TreeNode>
    </Tree>
  );
}
```

I see that the checked keys array has been logged four times as bellow inside the console:

```js
checked keys:=> []
checked keys:=> []
checked keys:=> ['efefefadcasd2323', 'saswdwdwfeewf']
checked keys:=> ['efefefadcasd2323', 'saswdwdwfeewf']
```

I want the tree nodes to be checked after getting the keys from server.

`Note:` The keys after fetching has been stored inside `redux` and for second time which I open the `AccessTree` component it has been rendered with checked keys as default.

Comment: Hi @szero, did you solve it? I have the same problem as you described...

Comment: I solved it, and here is [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49024787/4275509).