# Why is not tree checkboxes checked in the child component using Ant Tree Design

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree, antd

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong using this [Ant Tree component](https://ant.design/components/tree/).
I have two components, the PageAdmin I do a get call to get information about what nodes in the tree that should be marked as selected. I receive the data from the server and put it in the array `checkedKeys` and send it to the child component as props CustomTree and I can see the props for the CustomTree component are correctly updated, but the nodes in the tree are NOT selected, plus when I selected another node the `checkedKeys` array are cleared out and replaced with only the new selected nodes...

Any ideas what is happening?

**PageAdmin.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import TreeMenu from "./TreeMenu";
import CustomTree from "./CustomTree";
import axios from "axios";

import "./PageAdmin.css"

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000"

class PageAdmin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expandedKeys: [],
      autoExpandParent: true,
      checkedKeys: [],
      selectedKeys: [],
      treeData: [],
      treeID: this.props.match.params.id
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(`${BASE_URL}/eclass/all-nodes`)
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          treeData: result.data
        });
      })
    if (this.state.treeID) {
      console.log("yes we have a treeID")
      axios
        .get(`${BASE_URL}/eclass/custom/${this.state.treeID}`)
        .then(result => {
          this.setState({
            checkedKeys: result.data.checkedKeys
          });
        });
    }
  }

  handleCheckChange = (checkedKeys) => {
    this.setState({ checkedKeys });
    console.log("checkedKeys", checkedKeys)
  }

  handleSelectChange = (selectedKeys) => {
    this.setState({ selectedKeys });
    console.log("selectedKeys", selectedKeys)
  }

  handleExpandChange = (expandedKeys) => {
    this.setState({
      expandedKeys,
      autoExpandParent: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TreeMenu treeID={this.state.treeID} checkedKeys={this.state.checkedKeys} />
        <CustomTree
          onCheckChange={this.handleCheckChange}
          onSelectChange={this.handleSelectChange}
          onExpandChange={this.handleExpandChange}
          checkedKeys={this.state.checkedKeys}
          expandedKeys={this.state.expandedKeys}
          selectedKeys={this.state.selectedKeys}
          autoExpandParent={this.state.autoExpandParent}
          treeID={this.state.treeID}
          treeData={this.state.treeData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PageAdmin;
```

**CustomTree.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Tree } from 'antd';
import "./CustomTree.css"
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'

const TreeNode = Tree.TreeNode;

class CustomTree extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }

  onExpand = (expandedKeys) => {
    console.log('onExpand', arguments);
    // console.log('expandedKeys', expandedKeys);
    // if not set autoExpandParent to false, if children expanded, parent can not collapse.
    // or, you can remove all expanded children keys.

    this.props.onExpandChange(expandedKeys)
  }
  onCheck = (checkedKeys) => {
    // console.log('onCheck', checkedKeys);
    this.props.onCheckChange(checkedKeys);
  }
  onSelect = (selectedKeys, info) => {
    // console.log('info', info);
    // console.log("selectedKeys", selectedKeys)
    this.props.onSelectChange(selectedKeys);
  }

  renderTreeNodes = (data) => {
    return data.map((item) => {
      if (item.children) {
        return (
          <TreeNode title={item.title} key={item.key} dataRef={item}>
            {this.renderTreeNodes(item.children)}
          </TreeNode>
        );
      }
      return <TreeNode {...item} />;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Tree
        checkable
        onExpand={this.onExpand}
        onCheck={this.onCheck}
        onSelect={this.onSelect}
        checkedKeys={this.props.checkedKeys}
        expandedKeys={this.props.expandedKeys}
        autoExpandParent={this.props.autoExpandParent}
        selectedKeys={this.props.selectedKeys}
      >
        {this.renderTreeNodes(this.props.treeData)}
      </Tree>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomTree;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the bug and I would like to share how I solved it.

Before I did first got the tree node data and second I got the information about which nodes was selected. I had to make both request and update the state at the same time, as there are props for each Node (TreeNode) like `checked` and `halfChecked` that was not updated before, but now working with bellow changes in code.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(`${BASE_URL}/eclass/all-nodes`)
      .then(allNodes => {
        if (this.state.treeID) {
          console.log("yes we have a treeID")
          axios
            .get(`${BASE_URL}/eclass/custom/${this.state.treeID}`)
            .then(dataCheckedKeys => {
              this.setState({
                checkedKeys: dataCheckedKeys.data.checkedKeys,
                nameOfTree: dataCheckedKeys.data.nameOfTree,
                treeData: allNodes.data
              });
            });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            treeData: allNodes.data
          });
        }
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to set the property `checkedKeys` and `checkStrictly` properly.

`checkedKeys`: (Controlled) Specifies the keys of the checked treeNodes (PS: When this specifies the key of a treeNode which is also a parent treeNode, all the children treeNodes of will be checked; and vice versa, when it specifies the key of a treeNode which is a child treeNode, its parent treeNode will also be checked. When `checkable` and `checkStrictly` is true, its object has `checked` and `halfChecked` property. Regardless of whether the child or parent treeNode is checked, they won't impact each other.

Watch the documentation of antd for more info https://ant.design/components/tree/